# Which brain disorders cause better second language learning?

Tags: language

I heard that people with some types of synaesthesia may have advantage
for learning second language. I don't know it is true or not. But in general which kind of brain disorders cause better second language learning especially in adults?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.